# How execute command on server site?

Tags: magento-2.1

I have hosted my Magento site on the server.

My question is what I do after custom changes in Magento 2 on the server.

How will I execute the command on the server?

Comment: Do you have ssh for your server?

Comment: no i have not.please tell me how i get? cause i am beginner and that's first time i have host my site.

Comment: Do you have access to cpanel of website?

Comment: yes i  have find SSH.thank you very much to focusing to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client like [winSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), for example!

Comment: Still should work

Answer (score 0):

As you have got ssh, now you simply need to login to ssh and navigate to the root of magento (the directory where you have installed magento) and execute required command.

You can find reference for all magento cli commands here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html

Feel free to ping me if you need any other help